# How to save push notification data into local db when application closed in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

Able to store push notification data when app is in foreground and background(when launch notification).
But not on application killed or inactive state in iOS.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
       completionHandler([.alert, .sound, .badge])
   }
   
   func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
       defer { completionHandler() }
       guard response.actionIdentifier == UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier else { return }
       // perform action here
       
   }
```

WillPresent is calling when application is in  open state,

did receive is calling when  user taps on notification.

In these scenarios able to save notification data.

How to save data When application killed  and when no interaction with notification.

How to achieve this ?

Comment: You need to implement custom NotificationService. It is another application and will be hard to share database between 2 applications. But you can create application group and use it for user defaults. In our applications we get push notifications, store data in user defaults, which we can read from main application and do what we need on app start (remove data from UD to database, for example)

Comment: Hey I am facing same Problem. if you will find any solution. please let me know.